# Import the facebook sdk (4.17.0) with no gradle inside into an android studio's project

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0, import-module

I am trying to import the latest Facebook SDK (4.17.0 at the moment) but i noticed that the zip file is built differently than the formers Facebook SDK.
And when i'm trying to import it into android studio by going : File>> New>> Import Module, it gives me an eror message for the lastest fbk sdk :  "Specify location of the Gradle.
Screenshot : [import error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usD53.jpg)

I'm still new to android programmation, so i'm asking for your help to import the lastest Facebook sdk. 
Thank you by advance guys.

Screenshots of the zip comp :[root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZiOJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I up this question.
And i add some other question to it : on every example of Facebook sdk import i found, its mentioned that we need to create a new project in order to import fbk sdk. Is it just for the example? do we really need to create a new project to import the sdk, or can we just import it in an existing project ?